Who did most Arab Americans vote for in 2024?
I think this may not be answerable right away, but possibly an interesting question.
Various TikTokers etc. suggested voting for Jill Stein as "a vote for Palestine" since the mainstream options were supportive of Israel.
But from what I can tell Stein only got some 600K votes in 2024 thus far (same as RFK), compared to her getting 1.4M votes in 2016.

So for whom, if anyone, did most Arab Americans ultimately vote for in 2024? (As I see someone decided with VTC this requires non-public data: I'm asking for the usual measure based on exit polls. That's how we find/estimate how many women, minorities etc. voted for whom on every election.)

One source says Trump: https://www.timesofisrael.com/in-scene-unimaginable-4-years-ago-michigans-arab-americans-bask-in-aiding-trump-win/ 47% vs 28% vs 22% (Stein), at least in this particular community.

@Bobson - It will be interesting to see whether those results hold nationwide. And  even more interesting to see whether it has any effect on Trump's policy. He seems to have benefited from the incidental accident of not being the president when Israel started its invasion of Gaza, but based on his and his party's past political positions, it seems questionable whether he has any intention of, for instance, reducing arms sales to Israel.

This is indeed problematic in exit polling. Standard census definitions treat Arab Americans as "white" and most exit polls don't ask further about ethnicity. Arab Americans who don't identify as "white" often choose "other race" which is lumped in with lots of folks but mostly mestizo Hispanics and a variety of mixed race individuals. So, the answer you see isn't available from exit polling. The answer suggests a different good strategy to get some insight into an answer.

I am not posting this as an answer since it is a pre-election poll, but it probably gives some insight into how people actually voted. Basically, the poll found that Arab American voters were split about 50-50. However, Biden's electoral support among Arab Americans was never higher than 59%, and was 17% after October 7, 2023.

That is, Harris may have lost a little electoral support from Biden's high, and probably gained a lot from Biden's low. But again, not an answer, because nothing says that, e.g.  Harris could not actually have received 30% of votes nationwide because Stein got 20, say.

One place that has been synonymous with this voting constituency would be Dearborn, MI with about 55% of the city being Arab. Trump won the city

In Dearborn, where 55% of the residents are of Middle Eastern descent, Trump won with 42.48% of the vote over Vice President Kamala Harris, who received 36.26%, according to results, with 100% of precincts counted, provided to the Free Press from City Clerk George Darany. Jill Stein received 18.37% of the vote. Voter turnout in Dearborn was smaller compared to 2020.
Trump also won in Dearborn Heights, where 39% of the residents are of Middle Eastern descent, defeating Harris 44% to 38.3%, with Stein at 15.1%.
In the November 2020 election, Biden received 68.8% in Dearborn while Trump received 29.9%. Muslim voters interviewed Tuesday at polling sites said they were disappointed with the Biden administration's support for Israel's attacks and also preferred Trump's views on economics.


"Jill Stein received 18.37% of the vote." Stunning, but makes sense if someone sees both major candidates as bad on an issue like Middle Eastern foreign policy that matters to them. Stein plus Harris this year in Dearborn is roughly the same as Biden in 2020. Trump about the same each year and plausibly lots of those votes are non-MIddle Eastern residents of the town - given his expressed anti-Middle Eastern animus. Lots of conservative Muslims vote with the left in Europe because they aren't welcome on the right where there is closer agreement with their views on non-existential issues.

I don't think there's much question that most of the shift is due to the Biden administration's continued supply of weapons and economic support to Israel; how else to explain the change from four years ago? But such an abrupt change probably could not have occurred without some underlying substrate of conservatism receptive to Trump's actual policy prescriptions (e.g. the article cites Democrats losing some support even in 2022 after well-attended protests against LBGTQ book content by a portion—though by no means all—of the community).

@ohwilleke - Sure, if you combine Stein and Harris, the left-leaning vote still was greater than the right. That is, a majority of the Muslim and Arab American voters angry with Harris's intention to continue support for Israel were peeled off by a more left-wing candidate. But Trump gaining 13 percentage points is still noteworthy. At the very least, many voters believed—possibly incorrectly—that he would not be appreciably more supportive of Israel than Harris.

@Obie 2.0 Trump didn't  gain 13 percentage points, he only gained 6 percentage points. In Dearborn, Trump got 29.9% in 2020 and 36.26% in 2024. The 44% figure was in Dearborn Heights, a different suburb nearby, and not Dearborn. And a 6% point gain in Dearborn which is 45% non-Middle Eastern could easily come mostly from increased support for Trump among non-Middle Eastern people in Dearborn. (BTW, are you an Oberlin College alum? I graduated from Oberlin in '92.)

@ohwilleke - I think you may have mixed up the numbers. "In Dearborn, where 55% of the residents are of Middle Eastern descent, Trump won with 42.48% of the vote over Vice President Kamala Harris[...]In the November 2020 election, Biden received 68.8% in Dearborn while Trump received 29.9%." That's the approximately 13% difference. The value of 36.26%, at least according to the article, corresponds to Harris.

@Obie2.0 O.K., I stand corrected.

@ohwilleke I do strongly believe that the Biden / Harris campaign underestimated (and even deliberately ignored) the "uncommitted" movement to their own peril (especially from muslim voters). These were voters that had voted Democrats and were demanding that their the President / Government they had elected do something that was very much in their power to do so. And yet their voice was not only ignored but to add insult to injury most antiwar  protests were also prevented or attacked by the government. Far from even acknowledging their concerns, Biden was seen even defending Netanyahu (1/2)

by publicly claiming that there was no genocide in Gaza. It was thus no surprise (atleast to me) that these voters decided to punish Biden / Harris for ignoring them and switching their votes to Trump who atleast made the pretence of publicly stating that he would end the war and bring peace to middle-east. (Ofcourse, I remain skeptical of that). But to activist voters it does matter to them when politicians actually reach out to them and Trump did that efffectively - he very cleverly used his muslim connections (which I wasn't even aware he had) to reach out to the diaspora.

Source - https://thehill.com/homenews/state-watch/4966750-trump-arab-muslim-voters-michigan/ and  https://www.timesofisrael.com/in-scene-unimaginable-4-years-ago-michigans-arab-americans-bask-in-aiding-trump-win/

@sfxedit - Trump gained some, but it seems more likely that most of the voters that Harris lost went over to Jill Stein (you can see that she had about 18% in the city, whereas Trump gained about 13%). Stein is (correctly) perceived as against the Israeli war in Gaza, whereas Trump...well, Muslim bans aside, he left Middle Eastern policy plans to his son-in-law Jared Kushner last time, and Kushner's plan is to send Gazans to the Negev and turn Gaza into luxury waterfront property

@Obie2.0 You are right - I should have said "switching their votes to Stein and Trump". And I am sceptical of Trump. But I am still surprised at the gains made by Trump in the Arab American community, especially among muslims, because let's not forget that muslims were once the target of Trump's rhetoric. (Which is also why the Biden / Harris campaign perhaps very wrongly assumed that American muslim voters had no real choice but to vote Democrats). As for Kushner's plan, don't forget that Trump is a businessman - if Fatah or Hamas promises him his luxury hotel in Gaza he'll ditch Israel. :)

@sfxedit - Oh, Trump absolutely has no loyalty to Netanyahu, though he shares an affinity because of their shared right-wing authoritarianism (though Hamas would fit well there too!) But developing Gaza for Israelis could be pretty lucrative, whereas Hamas had much less money under the best of circumstances, and is now substantially worse off, and Fatah has not had any power in the Gaza Strip since Hamas won elections almost two decades ago. Both of them have far less now that Israel occupies pretty much all of Gaza. Neither is in a position to guarantee him a hotel, but Smotrich might be.

@sfxedit - While I am eternally hopeful that Trump (and Republicans and Democrats in the US congress) might indeed decide to put their foot down and break off support to Israel while it is engaged in a war that has caused at least tens of thousands of civilian deaths, it's not the most likely hypothesis. It seems more likely to me that after four years of Trump, Republican support of Israel, which historically has been firmer, will probably be fresher in the minds of voter.

@Obie2.0 What I believe is more likely to happen is that he will now pressure Israel to end the genocide in Gaza (after all, it's good PR) and as an alternate will encourage the Israelis to instead focus fully on Hezbollah to hurt the Iranians. If Hezbollah can be really weakened, there is good chance to bring Lebanese Christians to power there (which is good for his domestic politics). With his daughter's Lebanese father-in-law, it also makes sense as peace in Lebanon means good business opportunities for him. And if he also stops the war in Ukraine, he may even vie for the Nobel Peace Prize

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Leopards Eating People's Faces Party indeed.
