Did Kamala Harris lose more points by alienating anti-Israeli or pro-Israeli voters?
Has Kamala Harris lost more votes due to her perceived pro-Israeli stance (non-endrosement by uncommitted movement, and other Genocide Joe, Killer Kamala folks) or due to her perceived cosying to antisemitism?
I am mostly interested in statistical data and their analysis here. IMHO, both accusations are false - in her public rhetoric Harris mostly upheld the traditional American view of supporting Israel's right to exist alongside the Palestinian human rights, while opposing terrorism. Her attempts at positioning herself as a pro-Palestinian, were mostly lip-service to a popular cause, whereas her basic support to Israel largely aligns with the US interests in the Middle East.
Remark
I have change the title, since the debate in the comments has focused on ethnic vote, although the body of the question does not contain direct references to Jews/Arabs/Muslims, and questions of Israel, human rights, antisemitism, and terrorism are of importance to much broader groups.

Pretty related https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89687/who-did-most-arab-americans-vote-for-in-2024

Not opinion-based. It's answerable with polls. I'm sure the Democrats are going to do an election postmortem seeking to answer this exact question. Maybe the question isn't answerable until that postmortem is done, but that doesn't make it opinion-based. Voting to reopen.

@Allure: "Alienation" (and its effects on voting) is not something that is measured.

@user103496 The question is pretty clear that it asks for the polling data: I am mostly interested in statistical data and their analysis here I wish people start reading beyond titles.

I don't know what the answer is but note that neither group had the power to change the outcome of the US election, so neither group's vote mattered in the end. If every single Jew and Arab in America voted for Kamala, she would've still lost.

@JonathanReez - That's a weird statement. Trump won Penn by ~130,000 votes, Michigan by ~80,000 votes, and Wisconsin by  ~30,000 votes. Those three states have 44 electoral votes, which would have been enough to swing the election to Harris. There are over 10 million Jews / Arabs in the US, and in all three states the combined number is greater than Trumps victory margin. (It's actually about twice the margin in all three cases ~500,000 in Penn, ~250,000 in Michigan, and ~55,000 in Wisconsin.) -- This is an interesting and valid question.

@codeMonkey 1) You have to first substract the Jews/Muslims who already voted for Kamala, you can't just add 500k votes in Pennsylvania, you first have to substract the Jews/Muslim votes she already got there 2) You can't just take the total number of Jews/Muslims, you have to figure out how many are US citizens, 3) My comment was referring to people who show up to vote, not hypothetical voters, so you have to substract the people who don't show up to vote. In the end you'll end up with a Trump victory still happening.

@JonathanReez Right after this question was posted, it was almost closed.  I didn't think it should be closed, and I did a quick calculation using just Jewish voters in PA that showed that under some admittedly-extreme assumptions the swing in votes could approach a large enough value to possibly change the result in PA.  And that was only Jewish voters.  Unfortunately, that off-the-cuff analysis was cleaned out as the discussion over closing the question is no longer relevant, and I can't find the data I cited.  But yeah, it was close enough a different result might have been possible.

@JustMe I did a calculation just now and it’s impossible, assuming you don’t change the voter turnout. But feel free to add your answer.

@JonathanReez I'd think changes in turnout would be inherent in the question. Any candidate that alienates any set of voters who would otherwise vote for that candidate would both drive some to alternative candidates as well as cause some to not vote at all.  FWIW, I had to use 2020 numbers as the basis of my analysis as I couldn't find 2024 numbers when this question was posted just a few days after the election.

Gaza / Undecided Movement Probably didn't Change the Outcome
But they might have - it's a close thing.
We won't know for certain until / unless we get better polling, but Gaza policy almost certainly cost Harris Michigan. But even with Michigan, getting the rest of the Electoral votes she would have needed might have been a stretch.
Electoral Collage Math
For a Harris victory, she would have needed to take Pennsylvania, Michigan, and Wisconsin - those three states have 44 electoral votes, which is enough to put her over the 270 needed to win.
The margins in those states were ~130,000, ~80,000, and ~30,000 votes, respectively.
Arab Americans
According to the Arab American Institute, the Arab American population in those states are: 180,000, 500,000, and 60,000.
Dearborn Michigan is ~50% Arab American, and shifted from 75% Biden to less than 50% Harris (3rd parties got nearly 20% in 2024 in Dearborn).
So if Dearborn is representative of Arab Americans overall, and one quarter of Arab Americans would have otherwise voted for Harris, then Gaza / the Undecided movement may have cost Harris ~45,000 votes in Pennsylvania, 125,000 votes in Michigan, and 15,000 votes in Wisconsin.
This is enough for Harris to win Michigan, and to close the gap by half in the other two states.
Jewish Americans
Jewish Americans went for Harris and Biden at about the same margin, 80%.
There are over 400,000 Jewish Americans in Pennsylvania, and only about 30,000 in Wisconsin. So even if Harris completely captured the Jewish American vote, it probably wouldn't have changed the outcome in those states, since it would only gain her 80,000 and 6,000 votes respectively.
Overall
It's possible that Harris could have threaded a needle and pulled out a victory by changing her Gaza policy.
A full throated condemnation of Israeli policies would have almost certainly won Michigan, and  while Arab American don't have the numbers to swing the other two states, if excited Arab American voters managed to mobilize an additional ~90,000 Pennsylvanians and 15,000 Wisconsinites it could have turned the tide.
But the Jewish American vote is very large in Pennsylvania, so if that policy cost her any margin with the Jewish vote it would have put that critical swing state out of reach for Harris.

+1 However, I deliberately removed words like Jew/Arab/Muslim from the Q., because I suspect that many people concerned about Gaza do not belong to any of these categories - e.g., judging by the campus protests.

@Wagthemainstreammediadog - that's a great point! (but it's going to be harder to tease that out of what limited data we have)

If you are considering Jewish Americans, you should also consider American muslims (not just Arab Americans).

@sfxedit - a quick look at Wikipedia suggests the two groups are similar size in most states, and probably have something like a 40% overlap. So best guess is Harris could have narrowed the gap even more, but still would have lost Wisconsin and Penn even with a full throated condemnation of Israel. (WI would have been a nail-biter, though!) -- of course, if there's another demographic in play (eg, some subset of liberal white college students) that's another story, but I haven't found data to support that yet.

The Israeli Haaretz has a recent opinion article on this subject - Gaza? Antisemitism? Democrats' Online Witch Hunt Over Harris' Defeat Begins -  which concludes that Biden / Harris' attempt to "appease" both sides did lose it vote. (It however doesn't include any hard data).
But other Israeli and Jewish media certainly seem to suggest that Kamala Harris definitely alienated the Arab-Americans and "Uncommitted" anti-war voters, even though she overwhelmingly won the votes of the American Jewish community.
The Forward claimed in an article that Gaza didn’t cost Harris the election but her campaign cost her some of the Arab-Americans and American Muslim votes:

These appeals may have softened the Election Day impact of voters angry at Harris over her position on the Israel-Hamas war, given that polls have found about half of Democrats describe what is happening in Gaza as genocide. But she did bleed significant support in regions with large concentrations of Arab and Muslim voters, like Dearborn, Michigan, where Trump’s share of the vote grew from 30% in 2020 to more than 42% on Tuesday, and Stein, whose campaign uniform included a kaffiyeh, got 18%. Allentown, Pennsylvania, a ward home to many Syrian Americans, saw support for Harris drop nearly 15% compared to the share that backed Biden four years ago.
But Harris’ unwillingness to make serious concessions to voters unhappy with her position on Israel was indicative of a broader failure to make a convincing appeal to the left flank of the Democratic Party ... “The campaign’s approach on Gaza was similar to their approach on other issues, in terms of ignoring the overwhelming concerns of the base to court a white, Republican constituency that was always very unlikely to vote for them,” Borgwardt said in an interview.

The Times of Israel reports that 79% of US Jews voted for Harris, according to largest preliminary exit poll:

In recent decades, between 20 percent and 30% of American Jews have supported Republicans in national elections. The GOP hit a high-water mark in 1980 when Ronald Reagan won some 40% of Jewish votes, but the more typical split makes Jews among the most reliably Democratic demographics in the United States ... The National Election Pool, which produces an exit poll for a consortium of major news organizations, found that 79% of Jews said they voted Democratic, compared to 21% who voted Republican ...
If accurate, the National Election Pool’s result would be the lowest proportion of Jewish votes for a Republican presidential candidate in 24 years ... Fox News, which is right-leaning but has a reputation for reliable polling, conducted its own Election Day “voter analysis” ... It found that 67% of Jews voted for Harris, compared to 31% for Trump. The poll still found that Jews voted for Harris at higher rates than members of any other religion.

Forward cites similar data to reports that almost all voting groups shifted toward Trump, except American Jews and suggests that the American Jews are traditionally ideologically Democrat voters, worry more about America than Israel and thus stuck with Harris:

Exit polls showed that the two top concerns for most Americans going into the voting booth were democracy and the economy, and American Jews said the same. According to the exit poll done by Edison Research, 34% of Jewish voters said the state of democracy was their chief concern, followed by the state of the economy (31%), abortion (14%) and immigration (11%) ...
Why democracy? Jews make up 2.4% of Americans. Without voting rights, freedom of religion, free speech, the rule of law — all the safeguards democracy affords a minority — life for American Jews would be as tenuous here as it’s been for Jews throughout the world, throughout history ... And Jewish voters simply did not buy the Republican message that Harris posed a greater danger to democracy than Trump. They were not willing to risk the status quo on someone like Trump, who holds so little regard for the institutions and traditions that have long kept their community safe.

The Times of Israel and Jewish Telegraphic Agency both carried similar articles reporting that Trump explicitly didn't give any credit to the "Jews" for his win:

Trump hails ‘historic’ coalition that propelled his election win, doesn’t cite US Jews
Donald Trump thanked a ‘historic coalition’ for his election. He didn’t include Jews.

The Hill reported on March 2024 how the Trump campaign targetted the disaffected Arab-American Democrat voters, who felt ignored / betrayed by the Biden / Harris campaign and The Times of Israel reports on the success of these overtures -  :

It was a scene that was virtually unimaginable just four years ago, when Joe Biden won nearly 90 percent of the vote in the southern part of Dearborn, where a similarly overwhelming percentage of residents are Arab and Muslim. But riding the community’s utter fury over the Biden-Harris administration’s handling of Israel’s war against the Hamas terror group in Gaza, Donald Trump managed to win a plurality of the vote in Dearborn — 47 percent to 28% for Vice President Kamala Harris ... Attendees at the election watch party hailed from various areas throughout the Middle East — from the Palestinian territories to Lebanon, Jordan, Iraq, Syria and Yemen. But they were unanimous about their primary reason for backing Trump: They believe he can succeed in ending the ever-expanding Israel-Hamas war where Biden has failed.

Given that the majority in the U.S. disapprove of Israeli Action in Gaza (Mar 2024) it is quite clear (in hindsight) that Biden / Harris campaign made mistakes in handling the "Uncommitted" anti-war movement that did help them consolidate the American Jewish Democrat voters (and more importantly donors) while totally alienating many Arab American and American Muslim Democrat voters. And Trump benefited from it because his campaign specifically reached out to these voters and convinced many of them to not vote for Harris and to even consider him as a viable alternate.
While it is hard to conclude that the war in Gaza (or in Ukraine) played an important role in the defeat of Kamala Harris in the recently concluded American elections, Gallup poll (in my opinion) does hint that Trump's campaign position on both wars were possibly more attractive to American voters - Trump had an advantage over Biden / Harris on the perception of an American leader who could "keep U.S. safe from foreign threats".

Regarding "keep U.S. safe from foreign threats", the Republicans (and Trump himself) have portrayed the southern US border issue an foreign invasion by criminals etc. ("So has Trump at his campaign rallies: “This is like a military invasion. Drugs, criminals, gang members, and terrorists are pouring into our country at record levels. ... They’re taking over our cities.”") So  "keep U.S. safe from foreign threats" is even more vague/broad than Ukraine+Israel, as a poll question.

@264champagnebottlesonice I agree it is vague and prone to multiple interpretation. Another way to interpret it is by looking at Trump's own actions and words - in his previous term he was "war averse" and withdrew US military from conflicts and his current campaign promises included "ending" the war in Ukraine and "bringing peace" to middle-east quickly. Now that he has been elected by popular majority, I don't think it is a stretch to conclude that Trump's followers prefer his way of dealing with these "foreign events" that may prove to be a "threat" to US interests too.

I wouldn't rely on Israeli news sources so heavily for poll results, as it is a US election. I realize that you also included American sources, and would suggest more emphasis on them. Ha'aretz leans very left, but you balanced them with Times of Israel which was good.

@EllieK My thinking is that Israel has a vested interest in who the American Jews and American Muslims vote for because that has the potential to influence American foreign policy on Israel (which is true). In fact, that is why I believe Israeli media also focused on this aspect of the election more than American media (which has a more vested interest in promoting establishment views). I don't believe we are going to see any good analysis from the American media on this right now (perhaps in the distant future, 5 to 10 years from now).

You make a good point, about it being too soon to see any good analysis about this. That takes time, and the election was less than a week ago!

-1 because of the implication that Trump is somehow an anti-semite. You are aware that his daughter and son-in-law are practicing Jews, right? Both of them worked for his government in 2017-2021. Not mentioning a group != hating that group.

@JonathanReez That is your conclusion as I haven't insinuated that anywhere. In fact, I'd believe that Trump is actually apathetic towards any religious identity, and his politics has always been transactionally driven.

(Partial answer)
This source suggests that analysis is under way, with early results indicating that Harris indeed lost a lot of votes because of the Palestine issue. Exactly how many one can only guess (since the analysis is not complete), but:

Wa’el Alzayat, CEO of the Muslim American advocacy organization Emgage, guessed that Harris’ Muslim support might have come in as high as 90% if she had clearly signaled plans to break from Biden’s policy in the region. Emgage ultimately endorsed Harris, despite some of its members’ misgivings, arguing that “pursuing an anti-war agenda had a better shot under (the Democrat’s) administration.”

and

Four years after Biden dominated [in Dearborn, Michigan, which has a large Arab-American population], Trump got 42% of the vote, a plurality. Green Party nominee Jill Stein nearly cracked 20%. Harris landed in the middle, with 36%. According to national exit polls, more than 6 in 10 Muslims voted for the Democrat – a clear majority, but a stark decline from past cycles.

So if Wa'el Alzayat's guess is correct, 3 in 10 Muslims did not vote for Harris over the Biden administration's Middle East policy. There are about 4 million Muslims in the US. There were about 150 million votes cast out of 336 million population, so turnout is about 45%. If Muslims voted at the same rate as the rest of the country, then there were about 1.8 million Muslim votes cast. Of these, there were 30% "lost votes", or about 0.5 million.
I.e., an order of magnitude estimate is that Harris lost 0.5 million votes by alienating the pro-Palestine population. (This is likely an underestimate because it only counts Muslim voters.)
Trump leads Harris by 2.6 million votes country-wide, so espousing a pro-Palestine position probably would not have been enough to swing the election.
You might also be interested in this source, which suggests that the margin of victory in Michigan would've been much closer if Harris were pro-Palestine (200k voters affected; Trump won by 84k votes) - but even if Harris had won Michigan, it would not have been sufficient to win the election.

According to the Arab American Institute, 63% of Arab Americans are Christian -- so using religion as a proxy for sympathy for Palestine is probably a flawed approach. And - as 216 so recently demonstrated - winning the popular vote is not the requirement. Harris only needed ~250,000 more votes spread across three key swing states to seal a victory.

-1 because the votes of Muslims in non-swing states don’t matter. The only state Harris might’ve won thanks to the Muslim vote would’ve been Michigan, but that would’ve lost her the Jewish vote in other critical states.

Up vote because you quoted Pew Research (a very good, unbiased source) and because there is significant evidence that more Muslims voted for Trump than either Harris expected or many users on this site realize. Yes, it is true that the percentage of the Muslim vote is small overall; the same is true for Jews. However, the mayor of the only city in the US (Hamtramck, MI) w/an all Muslim city council endorsed Trump AND leaders of the Somali community in Minnesota (Omar Ilhan's district). The reasons they cited were the economy, education for their children, and dislike of Dem gender stances.

@JonathanReez That's why it's a partial answer. If you got better analysis, write your own answer.

Neutrality was the best policy, but not in a very meaningful way
Exit polls were pretty clear that Israel was not a major issue in the election.  Only 4% of voters considered foreign policy an important factor, and Ukraine and Tariffs were such "hot topics" in the foreign policy issue category, it is likely that Israel was not a deciding factor for more than 1% of Americans anyway.  On top of that, the American populus was very evenly split 3 ways about which side of the Israel conflict the US should be on weather we should be neutral, for, or against Israel.
By being such a strong supporter of Israel, Trump basically left Kamala with 2 options to set herself apart: strongly support Palestine and alienate the middle, or try to stay neutral which could make her own party less happy with her, but do a better job of bringing in swing voters.  Since the far left was going to vote for her either way, staying neutral on a relatively unimportant topic like this appeals to swing voters without driving her own party members into Trump's pro-Israel arms.
Any different strategy would have likely resulted in a worse outcome for Kamala, but since the topic was not important enough to influence the average voter either way, it probably did not swing the popular vote by more than a fraction of a percent.

The Far Left didn't vote for her, though. They just stayed home. She got something like 15 million less votes than Biden did in 2020.

@nick012000 It's much more likely that Biden just appealed to men and centralists a lot better.  15 million less votes does not mean 15 million less democrats voted.  It means that a lot of people willing to change their minds who supported Biden over Trump chose Trump over Kamala.

Harris is currently sitting at 9M fewer votes than Biden (72,378,170 vs 81,283,501).
